# Issues with PHP image upload

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I've been creating a HTML5 Drag & Drop image up-loader. All is good with the Javascript side of things however the PHP is driving me crazy!

I've been able to create a script that successfully places a image in a folder upon the drop of an image, however once it tries to create a thumb nail for the image and place the image link into the users db table it all goes to pot. I've sat here for hours on end, trying and trying to no avail, so i believe as it is now just about 3am GMT i should admit defeat and ask for a little help.

The JavaScript:

```
$(function(){

var dropbox = $('#dropbox'),
    message = $('.message', dropbox);

dropbox.filedrop({
    paramname:'pic',

    maxfiles: 5,
    maxfilesize: 200,
    url: 'uploadCore.php',

    uploadFinished:function(i,file,response){
        $.data(file).addClass('done');
    },

    error: function(err, file) {
        switch(err) {
            case 'BrowserNotSupported':
                showMessage('Your browser does not support HTML5 file uploads!');
                break;
            case 'TooManyFiles':
                alert('Too many files!');
                break;
            case 'FileTooLarge':
                alert(file.name+' is too large! Please upload files up to 200mb.');
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    },

    beforeEach: function(file){
        if(!file.type.match(/^image\//)){
            alert('Only images are allowed!');

            return false;
        }
    },

    uploadStarted:function(i, file, len){
        createImage(file);
    },

    progressUpdated: function(i, file, progress) {
        $.data(file).find('.progress').width(progress);
    }

});

var template = '<div class="preview">'+
                    '<span class="imageHolder">'+
                        '<img />'+
                        '<span class="uploaded"></span>'+
                    '</span>'+
                    '<div class="progressHolder">'+
                        '<div class="progress"></div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'; 


function createImage(file){

    var preview = $(template), 
        image = $('img', preview);

    var reader = new FileReader();

    image.width = 100;
    image.height = 100;

    reader.onload = function(e){            
        image.attr('src',e.target.result);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    message.hide();
    preview.appendTo(dropbox);

    $.data(file,preview);
}

function showMessage(msg){
    message.html(msg);
}

});
```

Now for the PHP:

```
<?php

// db connection
 include("db-info.php");
    $link = mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass);
        if(!mysql_select_db($database)) die(mysql_error());

 include("loadsettings.inc.php");


//$upload_dir = 'pictures/';
$allowed_ext = array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif');

if(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) != 'post'){
    exit_status('Error! Wrong HTTP method!');
}


if(array_key_exists('pic',$_FILES) && $_FILES['pic']['error'] == 0 ){

if (isset($_SESSION["imagehost-user"]))
   { 
      $session = true;
      $username = $_SESSION["imagehost-user"];
      $password = $_SESSION["imagehost-pass"];

      $q = "SELECT id FROM `members` WHERE (username = '$username') and (password = '$password')";
      if(!($result_set = mysql_query($q))) die(mysql_error());
      $number = mysql_num_rows($result_set);

      if (!$number) {
         session_destroy();
         $session = false;
      }else {
         $row = mysql_fetch_row($result_set); 
         $loggedId = $row[0];
    }
}


    $date = date("d-m-y");
    $lastaccess = date("y-m-d");
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $type = "public";

    $pic = $_FILES['pic'];
        $n = $pic;
            $rndName = md5($n . date("d-m-y") . time()) . "." . get_extension($pic['name']);
                $upload_dir = "pictures/" . $rndName;
                    move_uploaded_file($pic['tmp_name'], $upload_dir.$pic['name']);

                    // issues starts here

                     $imagePath = $upload_dir;

                     $img = imagecreatefromunknown($imagePath);
                        $mainWidth = imagesx($img);
                        $mainHeight = imagesy($img);

                        $a = ($mainWidth >= $mainHeight) ? $mainWidth : $mainHeight; 

                         $div = $a / 150;
                         $thumbWidth = intval($mainWidth / $div);
                         $thumbHeight = intval($mainHeight / $div);

                            $myThumb = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbWidth, $thumbHeight);
                             imagecopyresampled($myThumb, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbWidth, $thumbHeight, $mainWidth, $mainHeight);
                             $thumbPath = "thumbnails/" . basename($imagePath);
                             imagejpeg($myThumb, $thumbPath);

                             $details = intval(filesize($imagePath) / 1024) . " kb (" . $mainWidth . " x " . $mainHeight . ")" ; 
                             $id = md5($thumbPath . date("d-m-y") . time());


                             $q = "INSERT INTO `images`(id, userid, image, thumb, tags, details, date, access, type, ip)
                             VALUES('$id', '$loggedId', '$imagePath', '$thumbPath', '$tags', '$details', '$date', '$lastaccess', 'member-{$type}', '$ip')";
                                 if(!($result_set = mysql_query($q))) die(mysql_error());*/

                                    exit_status('File was uploaded successfuly!');

                            // to here


    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `blockedip` WHERE ip = '$ip'");
    $number = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($number) die(""); // blocked IP message

    function imagecreatefromunknown($path) {

        $exten = get_extension($path);

       switch ($exten) {
          case "jpg":
            $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
            break;
          case "gif":
            $img = imagecreatefromgif($path);
            break;
          case "png":
            $img = imagecreatefrompng($path);
            break;
  }

  return $img;
}


}

exit_status('Something went wrong with your upload!');

// Helper functions

function exit_status($str){
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>$str));
    exit;
}

function get_extension($file_name){
    $ext = explode('.', $file_name);
    $ext = array_pop($ext);
    return strtolower($ext);
}   

?>
```

Comment: _it all goes to pot_ is not an error message I've ever seen from a PHP/MySQL application. What errors are you seeing? What data inconsistencies?

Comment: Aside from the above, I really hope you are somehow sanitizing your inputs.. it doesn't look to be the case from here, if your script is live.  The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, consider [`PDO`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: I see a closing comment `*/` just after the `die(mysql_error())` that has no `/*` partner

Comment: You can check for syntax errors from the command line with: php -l path/to/file.php

Comment: From what i can gather the issue seems to be with the 'imagecreatefromunknown' function. calling the function seems to kill the upload process. @ Michael

Comment: I think there is a problem with your GD and image functions. Make sure that you have GD library of images for PHP so this will be able to work.

Comment: try changing the imagecreatefromunknown() value to  imagecreatefromunknown ( $upload_dir.$pic['name'] )

Comment: I don't want to derail your discussion, but you should try to use PDO (and, if you fancy it, a data abstraction layer) instead of mysql_* functions as they are being deprecated. Also, its much nicer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you pass wrong path to the `imagecreatefromunknown()` function. You pass `$imagePath` that equals `$upload_dir`, but your image destination is `$upload_dir.$pic['name']`